# PHP allow some HTML tags, write code in screen

Tags: php

I'd like to allow user to `add link in text, <b> and <code>`, so I do:

```
$texto = nl2br($texto);
$texto = strip_tags($texto, "<br><a><b><code>");
```

This will allow users to enter something like this:

```
<b>Some</b> text <a href="/someurl">Link</a> and 
<code>
<?php 
echo ""; ?>
</code>
```

The link will be a link, the bold text will be bold... 
The problem is the `<code>` tag. I'd like to allow users to place javascript, html, `<?php` but the code cannot run, only to show.

Any ideas how to allow some tags and the other ones I scape?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, I'd like to do something like the stackoverflow... @Kevin

Comment: The `<?php` in there should be encoded as `&lt;?php` to be what you mean. Same for any code samples of Javascript etc. It's really somewhat too late to fix this at this point.

Comment: @deceze like the `htmlentities` will do, but I'd like to allow some tags and escape the rest.

Comment: You can look into using something like http://htmlpurifier.org for this task, there's nothing in the PHP standard library that could do this kind of selective escaping.

Comment: The only idea I have is to replace the allowed tags `<a>` ==> `[a]` (For example), then escape the content and after that change back `[a]` to `<a>`

Comment: @AlonEitan oh, it is nice. Because I'm trying something like this: `str_replace(array("&lt;br /&gt;", "&lt;a href=&quot;", "&lt;a", "&lt;/b&gt;"), array("<br />", "<b>", '<a href="', "</b>"), $string);` but the A tag is a problem... can have blank_, quotes...

Comment: If you need to remove attributes like `target` then  htmlpurifier will do the work in this specific case. But it's indeed more complicated than it sounds :)

Comment: In general: if you accept literal HTML from your users, you are opening yourself up to a *huge* injection risk. You need to ***really*** know what you're doing to do this safely. Don't expect a simple replace or regex will work for everything here. Use a proven solution for this, like HTML Purifier.

Comment: So maybe BBCode could work @deceze?

Comment: @deceze oh, for sure! but in fact it is a blog, the users who post things will be admins, so it won't be a risk.

Comment: I did this to <a> tag:  `$texto = str_replace('&lt;a href=&quot;', '<a href="', $texto);
 $texto = str_replace('&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;', '" target="_blank">', $texto);
 $texto = str_replace('&lt;/a&gt;', '</a>', $texto); ` not the best solution but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). This function will escape tags from your code. So they will be printed instead of interpreted.

//edit because I read the comments.
I missed that you don't want htmlentities. In that case you could preg_replace "<" ( ">") with "&lt" ("&gt") in matching tags.

Comment: Read the comments: _"like the `htmlentities` will do, but I'd like to allow some tags and escape the rest"_

Comment: I missed that. In that case you could preg_replace  "<" ( ">") with "&lt" ("&gt") in matching tags. Regexp for this is fairly easy.

Comment: @matek997 thanks for your answer. it would be nice if you could give some examples... I need to allow <b><br><a><code> and use htmlentities to the rest.

Answer (score 0):

When someone create a post, I will allow links in it to have target _self (default) or _blank.

```
$texto = htmlentities($texto);

$texto = str_replace('&lt;a href=&quot;', '<a href="', $texto);
$texto = str_replace('&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;', '" target="_blank">', $texto);

$texto = str_replace('&quot; target=&quot;_self&quot;&gt;', '">', $texto);

$texto = str_replace('&lt;/a&gt;', '</a>', $texto);
```

I used target to know when to close the a href=" `">`

self_ will be the default link. The same I will do to b and code.

Comment: Doesn't work for any tags with any other attributes ( like "title")

Comment: @matek997 yes, it is not the perfect solution, works only for 2 cases. and the default link must have target _self to work.